# Is there any way to change font size on the whole Android device

Tags: android, fonts, settings

Is there any way to change font size on the whole Android device? i can change font size / color in my program but can I change it on the whole device? through coding

Comment: do you want it by your android application?

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. The user can adjust display settings to switch between four logical font sizes (small, normal, large, and huge). That is not a system setting that you can change yourself, through an SDK app, except perhaps on rooted devices.

Answer (score 0):

The device font can be changed using the below code. Not tested but still i'm sure its going to work.

```
Settings.System.putFloat(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.FONT_SCALE, (float) 1.0);
```

Please don't forget to add the `WRITE_SETTINGS` permission in your manifest like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

The changes will be affected after you restart the device.